# Поиск в списке словаря со значением в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть список заметок

```
notes = [
    {
        "title": "Заметка 1",
        "note": "Текст заметки 1",
        "tags": ["test1", "проверка1"]
    },
    {
        "title": "Заметка 2",
        "note": "Текст заметки 2",
        "tags": ["test2", "проверка2"]
    }
]
```

Надо искать только те словари в которых в значении ключа `tags` есть определённый текст.
Это можно сделать через `for`, но я бы хотел использовать более "заумный" способ для решении задачи.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вот немного заумней

```
text = 'проверка2'
print(list(filter(lambda x: text in x['tags'], notes)))
```